# Add a space between each character, but in a method

Tags: javascript, html, string

Hey :) I know a similiar question was asked before, but i just cant get it through. I want to create a method called something like makeMeSpaces, so my h2 text will have a space between each character.. and i might want to use it elsewhere aswell. I have this until now, from the logic point of view:

```
var text = "hello";
var betweenChars = ' '; // a space

document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = (text.split('').join(betweenChars));
```

it also works pretty fine, but i think i want to do

```
<h2>Hello.makeMeSpaces()</h2>
```

or something like this

Thank you guys!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function

Comment: Doesn't work like that, you should create an object with the attribute text and a method makeMeSpaces which returns the text

Comment: Why don't you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing ?

Comment: @Reeno because i want to solve this with javascript :)

Comment: when/where do you want to call method?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what type of function you are wanting ?

Comment: @turbzcoding please add more details of what you are trying to achieve , this kind of data provided are not enough to give a solution which works 100% according to you

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this in a 'reusable function,' you'd have to write your own:

```
function addSpaces(text) {
    return text.split('').join(' ');
}
```

Then, elsewhere in code, you could call it like so:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('h2');
elem.innerHTML = addSpaces(elem.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want , not exactly what you showed but some what similar

```js
Element.prototype.Spacefy = function() {
  // innerText for IE < 9
  // for others it's just textContent
  var elem = (this.innerText) ? this.innerText : this.textContent,
    // replacing HTML spaces ('&nbsp;') with simple spaces (' ')
    text = elem.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
  // here , space = "&nbsp;" because HTML ASCII spaces are "&nbsp;"
  space = "&nbsp;",
    // The output variable
    output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    // first take a character form element text
    output += text[i];
    // then add a space
    output += space;
  };
  // return output
  this.innerHTML = output;
};

function myFunction() {
  var H1 = document.getElementById("H1");
  // calling function
  H1.Spacefy();
};
```

```html
<h1 id="H1">
  <!-- The tags inside the h1 will not be taken as text -->
  <div>
Hello
  </div>
</h1>
<br />
<button onclick="myFunction ()">Space-fy</button>
```

You can also click the button more than once `:)`

---

Note :- this script has a flow, it will not work for a nested DOM structure refer to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170463/discussion-between-bgran-and-master-dark-night) to know more

[Here is a link to chat if you need to discuss anything](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170463/discussion-between-bgran-and-master-dark-night)

Here is a good [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjeVOG) provided by bgran which works better

Comment: If this is not what you want then please comment to let me know

Comment: What's the reason for down-voting this answer ? how can I improve it ?

Comment: As currently written, this answer adds a new message to the `Object` prototype, but the method accesses properties of `Element` (i.e. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)).

If `Spacefy` is called on any non-Element, this method will throw.

Comment: There are a few ways you could clean this up
1) Put the new function on the `Element` prototype, so it can't be called on objects that don't have the requisite properties
2) Use a method that doesn't require `prototype` mutations.

2) is preferable, because `prototype` mutations are difficult to reason about.

Comment: Okay , I did my changes take a look at it again

Comment: I've removed the down-vote but this answer still has some issues.

What happens if `innerHTML` isn't just plain text?

Comment: Thanks for canceling down-vote and also thanks for giving an idea of `Element` prototype

Comment: if innerHTML is plain text , then it'll do nothing , hence no need to worry

Comment: Try running this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjeVOG

This is almost definitely not the behavior OP wants.

This answer could actually cause OP some grief in the future if they try to use this method on an element with HTML content.

Comment: Try it again with innerTEXT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170463/discussion-between-bgran-and-master-dark-night).